# Firebase library not working in <= Lolypop devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my current project I'm using FCM for notifications. Its good and its working fine, but whenever I try to open the application in any device less than lolypop i.e. version 21 it crashes at the beginning.

I did check out a lot of SO posts, but never saw anyone has fixed it as an answer.

I'm using the latest version libraries as below

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
```

Please help, I need to provide support atleast upto jellybean devices.

CRASH LOG:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.arpaul.geocare, PID: 3127
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.arpaul.geocare-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.arpaul.geocare-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.arpaul.geocare-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.arpaul.geocare-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop
```

Comment: Can you post the crash log please?

Answer (score 1):

Your dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0` is including ALL the Google Play Services APIs, most of which you don't need.  This needlessly increases the size of your APK and build time. It is also probably causing the app to have more than 64K method references, which on older devices requires  Multidex, as [explained here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Instead, you should remove the dependency for `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0` and replace it with the specific APIs you need.  Instructions for that are [provided here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) in the section titled *Selectively compiling APIs into your executable*.

Comment: Yeah thats fine, but I need to use Firebase anyways and that is what is creating the problem.

Comment: The inclusion of the Firebase libs is not causing the problem.  The total set of libraries that are included is too large, causing the the Firebase methods to not be found.

Comment: Ok, will try out that too. I will be needing maps and auth and firebase as of now, will it work if I have maps and auth cause I can't find any play services for messaging?

Comment: Yes, include the Firebase APIs you need and only the specific Google Play APIs you use.  Or you can leave your dependencies the way they are and enable Multidex, although that is not the best long term solution.

Comment: I enable multidex in release version, did remove the gms lib as you said but that doesn't help. Still same issue.

Comment: If Multidex is working, you will see this message in `logcat` output at startup: `I/MultiDex: install done`.  Do you see that?

Comment: I initially did multidexenabled for release only, now I did for debug too, but In android studio Android Monitor this info doesn't come up. Are you sure there's no other problem?

Comment: I don't think Multidex is working.  Can you post your full build.gradle file and the part of your manifest that shows the attributes of the `<application>` element?  Did you set `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`?

Comment: Thanks I missed out a couple of things while doing the multidex, only enabled it in gradle file previously. Thanks a lot